# Difference between tMongoDB component in ESB and Big Data

Tags: mongodb, esb, talend, bigdata

1. what is the difference between tMongoDB component of talend ESB and tMongoDB component of talend Big Data?
2. which one is the best for handling data like (inserting new data, updating existing data, drop or deleting data etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

From my point view, mongodb components come from the same components package. It is integrated in multiple products like Talend ESB and Talend Big Data.